# How to get the storage space of a table in the MariaDB MyRocks storage engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb, rocksdb, storage-engines

I'm trying to get the space that a table using the MyRocks storage engine takes on disk and I'm getting inconsistent results between what I expect, a query on `information_schema` and the size as reported by the OS.

To get the size as reported by MariaDB, I'm using the following select statement:

```
select table_name 'Table Name',
      (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,3) 'Table Size in GB' 
from information_schema.tables where table_schema="MyTableName";
```

Which returns a really small number for what I'm doing, to the point where I'm doubtful that it's reporting the actual size (0.4GB for 4 000 000 rows with a lot of text).

If I run the command `du -h /var/lib/mysql/#rocksdb/`, I'm getting a disk size of 2.4GB, which is a bit more than what I would expect. However, if I understand correctly, MyRocks compacts data as data is inserted, so it's possible that the disk space reported by the `du` command is unrepresentative of the actual table size.

So, is there a reliable method to get the size of a table? Am I already using the correct way to get the table size?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use `POWER(1024,3)` instead of `POWER(2014,3)` assuming that storage engine is MyISAM:

```
select table_name AS `Table Name`,
      (data_length+index_length)/power(1024,3) AS `Table Size in GB` 
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema='MyTableName';
```

And calculation:

```
(data_length+index_length)/(2014*2014*2014) = 0.4
=> 
(data_length+index_length) = 3267671497,6

3267671497,6/(1024*1024*1024) = 3.04GB
```

> **[DATA_LENGTH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html)**
>
> For MyISAM, DATA_LENGTH is the length of the data file, **in bytes**.
>
> For InnoDB, DATA_LENGTH is the approximate amount of memory allocated
>   for the clustered index, **in bytes. Specifically, it is the clustered
>   index size, in pages, multiplied by the InnoDB page size.**)

Comment: Hi Lukasz, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this was a typo when I wrote the question. I was actually using 1024. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @CydrickT You could also try `MAX_DATA_LENGTH` instead `DATA_LENGTH`

Comment: In what way would I be using this variable? Also note that the storage engine is MyRocks, which is relatively new.

Comment: I would not expect Max... to be relevant.  3x is a typical shrinkage factor for text; you are getting 6x.  InnoDB tends to be 2x-3x bigger on disk than MyISAM; I don't know about MyRocks.

Comment: Just tried it with `max_data_length` and the result is even smaller than `data_length`, so it does not make more sense to me.